Making object shifted to the side responsive with orthographic camera Three js
I’m trying to figure out the best way to make the position (and scale if needed) of the model across all devices without relying only on match medias. Ofc I can’t use %, so is there something built into Three.js that could help me achieve the best result? Also any other solution (if someone has it) is much appreciated. Right now I am using a orthographic camera in my scene.
This is what happens:
I want the model to position like this

But of course when I resize the screen it gets cut out like this

My resize code is as simple as this:
rendererSize.width = window.innerWidth;
rendererSize.height = window.innerHeight;

aspect = rendererSize.width / rendererSize.height;

//* [ORTHOGRAPHIC CAMERA]
camera.left = -f * aspect;
camera.right = f * aspect;

camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
renderer.setSize(rendererSize.width, rendererSize.height);


Maybe try manipulating model scale or position according to screen size instead of manipulating camera?

You are on the right track, but missing one point.
It looks like the anchor of your model could be representated as vec2(0.5, 0.5).
If you set the position of your object to vec3(0, 0, 0), you will see that the object is absolutely centered, meaning that the center of your object is also the center of your screen.
Most likely, in your resize function you add half screen size as position.x.
Meaning that you move that anchor half screen away, so half of your object would be hidden. You need to substract half the width of your object to your offset.
You can get the width of your object by getting the boundingBox.

After messing around a bit I figured out a way that is a bit clunky but works fine. But this is actually a really smart solution, I will need to use the orthographic camera in other projects so I will definitely try this out!
